# Extracting x from (Just x) in a Maybe

Tags: haskell, types, option-type

Super simple I'm sure, but I can't seem to find the answer.  I call a function that returns `Maybe x` and I want to see `x`.  How to I extract `x` from my `Just x` response?

```
seeMyVal :: IO ()
seeMyVal = do
   if getVal == Nothing 
   then do
       putStrLn "Nothing to see here"
   else do
       putStrLn getVal -- what do I have to change in this line?

getVal :: (Maybe String)
getVal = Just "Yes, I'm real!"
```

This throws the error:

```
Couldn't match type ‘Maybe String’ with ‘[Char]’
Expected type: String
  Actual type: Maybe String
In the first argument of ‘putStrLn’, namely ‘getVal’
In a stmt of a 'do' block: putStrLn getVal
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a standard function with this signature, [`fromJust`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:fromJust).

Use Hoogle for searches like this one, [it's a wonderful tool](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Maybe+a+-%3E+a).

Comment: This is a very dangerous tool for such a task, since it crashes the whole program if it happens to find `Nothing`. Code such as `if isJust ... then fromJust ... else ....` is not idiomatic in Haskell, and should be not suggested since safe alternatives do exist.

Comment: I did not suggest this code. What I suggested was 1) a function with the signature OP wanted; 2) a way to find functions by signature in future. I know nothing of what OP wants to do with it; it's perfectly fine to use it e.g. on a hardcoded map where you know the key you requested exists, and if it doesn't it should be filled in.

Comment: Hoogle is always a good suggestion, yet as already said in this case its result is more harm- than helpful, so it should only be a comment with big caveat.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: no, it shouldn't be a comment, because it answers the question. If you don't like it, don't upvote/accept it. There is no caveat, the error-throwing behavior is clearly documented. I honestly don't understand all this hate for `fromJust`, there are plenty of cases where throwing an error is an acceptable and logical thing to do.

Comment: @fjarri: throwing an error is seldom a good idea, except when you're already in the `IO` monad (only there can errors properly be caught), or if you just want to add an “idiot proof” assertion that really should never fire unless triggered by some bug. Even so: for exceptions that aren't really all that exceptional, a proper `Either`/`ErrorT` type is the way to go. And assertions should also give some useful debug information, which `fromJust` scarcely does. A non-exhaustive pattern match will give a much more helpful error message.

Comment: And finally: using partial functions is just completely unnecessary here! A proper exhaustive pattern match, as shown by Danial Wagner, is better _in every regard_.

Answer (score 20):

The idiomatic way is to pattern match.

```
seeMyVal = case getVal of
    Nothing  -> putStrLn "Nothing to see here"
    Just val -> putStrLn val
```

If you like, you can factor the `putStrLn` out:

```
seeMyVal = putStrLn $ case getVal of
    Nothing  -> "Nothing to see here"
    Just val -> val
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be more idiomatic if you had two instances for different constructors, like `seeMyVal Nothing = ...` and `seeMyVal (Just val) = ...`?

Comment: @fjarri Not more idiomatic, I think, just different: that would define a function, whereas this defines a plain old `IO ()` action.

Answer (score 10):

You can also use [fromMaybe](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:fromMaybe), which takes a default.

`fromMaybe "Nothing to see here..." (Just "I'm real!")`